statistical significance of difference of a binary variable between two groups
I have a summary table like the one below (left side n:690 - area x, right side n:1213 - area y; just an example).



A
B
Total
A
B
Total




10
2
12
72
47
119


83,33
16,66

60,50
39,49



58
5
63
136
11
147


92,06
7,93

92,51
7,48



575
115
690
976
237
1213


83,33
16,66

80,46
19,53




This is the count and percentage of observations which have been assigned binary value A or B as the result of the same calculation. The data is cross-sectional time-series data. As per theoretical underpinnings we know there shouldn't be significant differences between the two areas. I would like to know if I can arrive at conclusions such as
"2 out of 12 observations in area X are assigned value B in comparison to 47 out of 119 in area y, therefore this binary assignment does not apply to area X".
---edit---
This is the manifesto project data, a dataset where political parties are given scores on various issue categories. I am looking at how well a concept travels beyond the area it was developed in. The A and B binary assignments are whether a party is "niche" or "mainstream", as a result of a calculation based on the scores of those issue categories. There are 10 "families" of parties (e.g: greens, nationalist, social democrats, etc). The first group, greens for example, have 10 observations identified as mainstream on the left hand side; and 72 observations identified as mainstream on the right hand side. My assertion is, using this measurement it is not possible to analyze some groups reported on the left hand side because the measurement fails to identify correctly. The reason for this is because we wouldn't expect such big differences between the two areas with respect to some groups that are thematically relevant (greens and nationalists present huge differences). I am able to back my claim up using the properties of said concept and components of the calculation (there is an economic component to the calculation which impacts the binary variable more than other components, and I can show this component is the reason for high differences).
for reference, for other measure where the outcome is continuous, I am using t-test to show that the difference of means is significant. but here the binary variable confuses me.
---end of edit---
What kind of test would show if the difference is statistically significant? I have been looking at chi square and z tests but I am not entirely sure if it is possible to make the point I want to because I am a noob. Thank you very much in advance.

Most of the data you present need descriptions--but I suspect they might be irrelevant to your question.  Can't everything be summarized in the $2\times2$ table of counts of $A$ and $B$ for the two areas $X$ and $Y$?

thank you for taking the time. that is entirely possible. the fact that some groups have really low size like 12 worries me a little. I just want to be able to report results in a statistically solid way. It seems I forgot to mention I want to look at each group individually,  and there are 10 of them.

The answers depend so much on seemingly minor details that I warmly encourage you to modify your post so that (1) it describes the data and problem you actually have and (2) explains all tables or graphics you might use for (1).

thank you very much, I edited the question. I was trying to avoid such a long question but here we are!

Your explanation is still a bit confusing to me. You say A and B are supposed to represent "niche" and "mainstream", but then later say that 10 Greens are mainstream and 72 are niche, which are both under the A category. Am I missing something here? In any case, this seems to be a contingency table that involves counts within two categories. You ought to organize the table to look like that instead.

hello shawn! sorry it wasn't clear. these are two different region. left hand side niche & mainstream parties in central and eastern europe - right hand side in western europe. both niche and mainstream categories exist for both regions and all families. apparently the answer is a z-test.

How does a z-test answer this question? Typically that is reserved for a comparison of a sample mean to a population mean. Here you clearly have two factors as IVs and a count as your DV, which wouldn't apply to a z-test. I'm also lost on how this is considered "cross-sectional time series" data. This isn't a time series, and time series can't be considered cross-sectional by definition. Also: where does the "continuous" outcome fit into all this? It would help to have more information there, particularly what hypothesized model you are trying to test with all of these variables.

so the data covers 31 countries for a time period of 1990 - 2022 with a total of 2501 observations. I am testing 4 different measures on this data. because in this measure the outcome is binary, i just shared a small part of the summary table. I want to look at whether the proportion of niche parties in one sample is significantly different than the second sample. my assertion is if it is significantly different the concept doesn't travel well. ts is not important for this question, I report the change of single variables in time in sections - and a comparison of sections; thats what i meant.

as mentioned, continuous outcome is for another measure, not this one. I think you might have overlooked some details in the question. I understand it is not clearly formulated maybe because I lack the terminology, but i believe it should be understandable :) I mentioned this only as a frame of reference.
